# Creating a loop that will edit 60 TextBox names?

Tags: c#, loops

text box set1 =  1 to 30 = in the query 
name = br1id to br30id

textbox set 2 = 1 to 30 = in the result output

i dont understand how to create a loop based on 30 diffrent textbox names?

i cant copy paste these lines 30 times editing the textbox names, that wold just look wrong.

```
try
{

   MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(
      "server= 195.159.253.229;" +
      "Database = bruker;" +
      "user id=bobby;" +
      "password=LoLOW###;");  

   MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(
      "SELECT brukernavn From bruker where ID = '" + br1id.Text + "';", mysqlCon);

   mysqlCon.Open();

   navX[0] = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
   br1txt3.Text = navX[0];   
}
```

Comment: Why, in the name of all that is good and holy, do you have 600 text boxes?

Comment: I can't check it but I hope for you that your user id and password doesn't work.

Comment: i dont have 600 i have 60, but the problem is still the same, i used 600 just as a way to magnefy the problem :P, the loop is to populate textboxes with values in a DB in a tool im working on for statistics reasons, it cold have been 600 if i wanted to :P.

and no ZippyV ofc the login is bougus, but i recon alot of script kiddies already trying and cant wait to try to get info from the bogus db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use a control enumerator.

Assuming that this is WinForms:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls) {
    if(c is TextBox)
        Console.WriteLine(c.Text);   
}
```

And actually, I think that will work for ASP.Net, too.  (Even though Control is in a diferent namespace.)

HOWEVER!:  This is what a datagrid was made for.

Comment: yeah i was thinking about enums thats prolly the path i need to walk yeah.

Answer (score 1):

You really should reconsider your design if you have 600 `TextBox` controls. Holy cow.

Also, your SQL is very much subject to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

What you're looking to to *specifically* can't be done, as there is no dynamic evaluation of C# at runtime. What you need to do is create a collection of the controls you want to use--in the order you want to use them--then enumerate over this list to use in your query. However, this query should absolutely be rewritten to use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get a control by name inside a Form:

```
        // get control by name:
        TextBox tb = this.Controls["textBox1"] as TextBox;
        if (tb != null) {
            // your code here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes to all previous answers, (600 textboxes?  600 for Ids and 600 more for the query results?)  but if you really want to do this, as a technique, also change the SQL to:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
         "SELECT brukernavn From bruker where ID In (");
foreach(Textbox tb in IdTextboxes)  sb.Append(tb.Text + ",");  
string SQL = sb.ToString(0,sb.Length - 1) + ")";

MySqlConnection mysqlCon = 
     new MySqlConnection("server=195.225.0.218; " +
          "Database = bruker; user id=huggy; password=LoLOW;");   
cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(SQL, mysqlCon);
```